# JavaScript text between double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, text, substring

I would like to get the text between double quotes using JavaScript. I found online something like `title.match(/".*?"/);` but the thing is that sometimes I have text between double quotes but sometimes there are no quotes. What I am saying is that sometimes I receive strings like: `Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum` and sometimes strings like: `Neque "porro quisquam est" qui dolorem ipsum`. The thing is, when I have text containing double quotes I want to retrieve the text between them but when they aren't present, I'd like the whole text.
Also I have observered that `string.indexOf("\"")` does not work and I don't really know how to approach this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try:

```html
<script>
let str1 = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum';
let str2 = 'Neque "porro quisquam est" qui dolorem ipsum';
let str3 = 'Neque "porro';
let str4 = 'Neque "porro" quisquam "est" qui dolorem ipsum';

function extractFirstText(str){
  const matches = str.match(/"(.*?)"/);
  return console.log(matches
    ? matches[1]
    : str);
}


function extractAllText(str){
  const re = /"(.*?)"/g;
  const result = [];
  let current;
  while (current = re.exec(str)) {
    result.push(current.pop());
  }
  return console.log(result.length > 0
    ? result
    : [str]);
}

// Execution of the functions

extractFirstText(str1);
//Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum

extractFirstText(str2);
//porro quisquam est

extractFirstText(str3);
//Neque "porro

extractFirstText(str4);
//porro

extractAllText(str1);
//Array [ "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum" ]

extractAllText(str2);
//Array [ "porro quisquam est" ]

extractAllText(str3);
//Array [ "Neque \"porro" ]

extractAllText(str4);
//Array [ "porro", "est" ]
</script>
```

**EDIT** reworked to take into account both @AshishMaity comment in a discarded edit about matching more than one substring, and @JosephCho comment about the original breaking in case there is a single quote (str3 in the case above)

Comment: A simple and effective solution. Thanks!

Comment: This solution tosses an error if there is only one quotation mark! Is there a more robust solution?

Answer (score 19):

try it with this one:

```
/"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dAZXdKTQ34eVUpei)

Answer (score 10):

In a single regex:

```
var m = s.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|^[^"]*$)/)[0].replace(/"/g, "");
```

**TEST:**

```
s = 'Neque "porro quisquam est" qui dolorem ipsum';
m = s.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|^[^"]*$)/)[0].replace(/"/g, "");
//=> porro quisquam est

s = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum';
m = s.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|^[^"]*$)/)[0].replace(/"/g, "");
//=> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum
```

Comment: yeah, it works like a charm but I want the text without the " " .. any idea on how the regex should be modified in order to get rid of the " " ?

Comment: `match(/"([^"]*)"$/)[1]`

Answer (score 3):

split() function can be used get value in double quote

```js
let str1 = 'Neque "porro quisquam est" qui dolorem ipsum';
let str2 = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum';

function findFirstOccurance(str){
  const matches = str.split('"');
  return matches[1] ? matches[1] : str;
}


console.log(findFirstOccurance(str1));
console.log(findFirstOccurance(str2));
```