# How can I write a Regex to match double quoted strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regex which is able to match double quoted strings.
Here is what I have:

```
regex = /\"(\\\"|[^\"])*\"/g
```

It works for almost all cases. But there is a case for which it does not capture the string correctly. For instance if the input is "\" it should not capture it as a double quoted string, since \" would be a the character '"'. For this purpose I tried to figure out the condition required, which it is:

- If the previous character of the closing double quote is '\' do not capture it. But honestly I don't know how to express this into the regex expression.

I would appreciate some tips and help to get this done.
Thanks beforehand

Comment: I think `"(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*"` is the better approach to this.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript text between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793221/javascript-text-between-double-quotes)

Comment: By the way, double-quotes don't need to be escaped when using the `/pattern/` constructor, so `\"` and `\\\"` could be simply written `"` and `\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(?:[^\\\"]|^)\"([^\"]*)\"`